# Local Multiplayer Server architecture on android

Tags: android, html, architecture, multiplayer

I would like to create a local multiplayer server.
My idea would be like this.
Server phone starts a server and any other device calls the server over wifi and see a html5 app. So the client devices doesn't need to download the app.

Are there any good frameworks which supports such a behavior?

I found already i-jetty (https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/wiki/ConsoleWebApplication), but according to the wiki i need to download the app before. Another thing is I dont know how to access a database over calls to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big topic you are asking. A good starting point would be to investigate web services to get your database via a web server.

I'd recommend looking at Web Services..this is a very basic link:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_use.asp

Comment: thx for you answer. I am familiar with webservices, but how can i write a webservice wich runs on an android phone

Comment: Ah..sorry I misunderstood your question, my bad, I assumed you wanted the database hosted centrally on the web and to perform CRUD operations to it from your app via http..